# Spring AOP: Advice on annotation used over another advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, java-annotations

I have created my custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Condition {
    String value();
}
```

I want to use this annotation to determine whether or not to run advice, my try:

```
@Condition("some.config")
@Around("execution(public * someMethod())")
Object doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // some logic here
}

@Around("@annotation(condition)")
Object checkCondition(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Condition condition) throws Throwable {
    String property = (String) configuration.getProperty(condition.value());
    if (Boolean.valueOf(property)){
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works when I use `@Condition` on some other methods, i.e. the `checkCondition` is applied and then the method is executed or not based on config value. For advice `doSomething` it doesn't get applied though.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work for advice"? Share [mcve] code.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Why would it be expected to be applied if that's your custom annotation, and nothing apart from your own code knows about it?

Comment: Maybe because this is all my own code? Why are you so aggressive? I'm just new to spring-aop and trying to mess around with it a little bit.

Comment: Agressive or not, *why do you think that your own custom annotation would make any difference to the code that knows nothing about it, without you writing the code?*. Spring AOP advices are also not Spring components themselves, and are not considered for wiring. It may also work like that for aspectJ in general, otherwise pointcuts that are just a little too general would go in infinite loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your aspect works for other components, just not the aspect itself. From this statement I gather that

1. your aspect is wired correctly (e.g. annotated with `@Component` and detected by component scan or wired manually via XML config) and
2. you use proxy-based Spring AOP.

In (2) is the source of your problem. According to the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-at-aspectj) aspects themselves are exempt from being aspect targets themselves:

> **Advising aspects with other aspects?**
>
> In Spring AOP, it is not possible to have aspects themselves be the target of advice from other aspects. The @Aspect annotation on a class marks it as an aspect, and hence excludes it from auto-proxying.

So *M. Prokhorov* is somewhat wrong when saying that aspects are not (or cannot be) Spring components, but he is right insofar as by design you cannot self-advise an aspect or advise other aspects. His assumption that it *may* work with AspectJ is also correct. It *does* work with AspectJ, so if you need it to you can configure Spring to use [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead of Spring AOP for this case.

Comment: Since the initial goal was simply to enable or disable aspects based on some configuration property, then [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406192/can-we-enable-or-disable-aspect-based-on-value-of-any-flag-or-through-configurat) is also quite helpful.

Comment: Yes, for Spring AOP the solution based on `@ConditionalOnExpression` seems to be a nice way to achieve that. I am not a Spring user, though, so usually I am looking for Spring-independent solutions. If it is really just about en-/disabling an aspect based on a condition, a few years ago I showed how to do that [dynamically via JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24017288/1082681). The used `if()` pointcut from AspectJ is not available in Spring AOP. It could be replaced by an `if` expression directly in the code if a switch to AspectJ is not desired.